# tkinter, text does not change immediately on mac osx

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, osx-mavericks

But it changes immediately on Ubuntu after clicking the button. On Mac, it changes when the mouse moves out of the root window.

By the way, the msg box is centered in the root window on Ubuntu, it is centered in the screen on Mac as expected.

```
#coding=utf8
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox as mb


class App(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title('Root')
        self.root.geometry("500x500")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.set_var()
        self.content.pack()
        self.button.pack()
        self.frame.pack()

    def set_var(self):
        self.var = tk.StringVar(value="hello")
        self.content = tk.Label(self.frame, textvariable=self.var)
        self.button = tk.Button(self.frame, text='Show', command=self.var_change)

    def var_change(self):
        self.var.set("world")
        mb.showinfo("Title", "Hi", parent=None)
        self.var.set("hello")


def main():
    app = App()
    app.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a call to `update_idletasks` after you change the label - it forces the application to finish any waiting tasks before moving on:

```
def var_change(self):
    self.var.set("world")
    self.root.update_idletasks()  # This forces the window to update
    mb.showinfo("Title", "Hi", parent=None)
    self.var.set("hello")
```